# NTFS Junctions, trouble understanding the API

Tags: winapi, ntfs, junction, reparsepoint

**Update**: This question has *evolved* into a question about the `NTFS filesystem filter driver` how to use the Win32 API in backup applications and other programs that need to know **what a file really is on disk**? Junctions and **reparse points** are key concepts that I needed to consider and are the most confusing thing in the NTFS filesystem.

*The original question follows:*

---

1. What is the **Win32 API** used to *detect* if a directory is a junction?
2. 'Where' (for lack of better understanding) in the NTFS hierarchy are junctions stored?
3. If I create a junction `c:\thejunction_mydir` **do *both* directories become junctions of one-another**? i.e. the *created* and the *referenced*

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detect Symbolic Links, Junction Points, Mount Points and Hard Links](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2487237/detect-symbolic-links-junction-points-mount-points-and-hard-links)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### How do I detect a reparse point?

**[Determining Whether a Directory Is a Mounted Folder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363940.aspx)** is the answer. It shows how to determine whether a folder is a *reparse point*, and thus if it is also potentially: a Junction or a Symlink or a Mount-point.

Comment: This isn't actually true. Junctions are not like hardlinks; they are like softlinks in that they are just a pointer to a path, and not a second reference to the same location on the disk.

Comment: But Windows Vista and up have a different softlink called a symbolic link, and that is recommended over Junctions any day.