# How to get the actual directory path on windows using .NET?

Tags: .net, windows, junction, reparsepoint

My need is simple. Given a Windows directory path all I want is the actual path. I am sure the terminology is wrong, so I am giving an example.

Given **C:\Documents and Settings\All Users** the method should display:

- **C:\ProgramData** on windows 7
- **C:\Documents and Settings\All Users** on windows 2003

This is because on windows 7 **C:\Documents and Settings** is a junction referencing **C:\Users** and **C:\Users\All Users** is yet another junction referencing **C:\ProgramData**, which is the actual directory.

So, my question is what .NET API lets me do all this?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2240734/c-how-to-retreive-the-target-of-a-junction-or-symlink-with-a-standard-user) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4571622/ntfs-junctions-trouble-understanding-the-api)

Comment: You are right, but only partially. No .NET API is given and although I can try and use P/Invoke, this is not the preferred choice.

Comment: I agree. Apparently the only way is through P/Invoke. Voted to close.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this code sample](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/files/JunctionPointsNet.aspx) from someone who has figured it out already.

Essentially, you have to use the Win32 function [DeviceIoControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363216%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) via P/Invoke passing the `FSCTL_GET_REPARSE_POINT` as the `dwIoControlCode` parameter.

As the guy on CodeProject says...

> I find it interesting that the .NET
>   Framework's FileAttributes enumeration
>   includes the value
>   FileAttributes.ReparsePoint but there
>   is no other built-in support for
>   Reparse Points.

There is no "native" .NET API to do this, but bear in mind that much of the framework is just a wrapper around P/Invoke calls anyway, so you shouldn't fear them :)