# How to ensure I can uniquely identify a directory path in .NET

Tags: c#, .net

I've just found a bug in my application where `Path.GetFullPath()` does not return *exactly* the same result for different representations of the same path. In this case, `../include` and `../include/` are returning `c:\\...\\include` & `c:\\...\\include\\` respectively; since I maintain a `Dictionary<string,...>` for dir names this breaks things.

How can this be fixed, ideally without nastly kludgy checks on strings but using framework methods?

Comment: do you need the last @"\"?

Comment: It doesn't matter if I need it, this is input data from an external source which can contain either version.

Comment: can you do a trimend('\\')?

Comment: Looks like it might be a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281531/how-can-i-compare-directory-paths-in-c

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`../include` may point to a directory *or* a file (files don't have to have an extension), and `../include/` always is a directory because of the trailing slash. So they are definitely not the same.

If *you* are sure the input always are directories (which `Path.GetFullPath()` can't be sure of), you can do:

```
path = Path.Combine(input, Path.DirectorySeparatorChar.ToString());
```

This way all input will be seen as directories, not files, and `Path.GetFullPath()` will return the same for both variants.

Comment: In _this_ context, they _are_ the same... an external file has a list of additional dirs so if someone has put in a file-name, the data is bad in the first place. I already check the path is a valid directory explicitly.

Comment: Yes, you know that, but Path.GetFullPath() doesn't, because that's a string operation, not a filesystem operation. Just make all paths end with a trailing slash then to help it a little.

Comment: Or sorry, I see what you mean. Shouldn't `@"\"` be the proper dir-separator constant though, strictly speaking?

Comment: @John yes, that would even be cleaner, look at [`Path.DirectorySeparatorChar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.directoryseparatorchar.aspx)`.ToString()`.

Comment: I need to correct my string vs filesystem remark: _" Note that unlike most members of the Path class, this method accesses the file system. "_

Answer (score 0):

They shouldn't return the same result. If you need to check if the path is actually a file or a directory you can use `Path.GetFullPath("../include")` Without the trailing slash. If the paths are provided programatically then do a  `string.TrimEnd('\\')` and then check if the path is a file or a directory using:

[File.Exists()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists.aspx) and [Directory.Exists()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.exists.aspx) to determine if the specified path is a file or a directory.

You need to make sure that all your table insertions and searching is done by inserting/comparing with non trailing slash paths.

Answer (score 0):

do a .TrimEnd('\') if it's plausible.