# How do I check equality of relative file paths

Tags: c#, .net

I need to check whether two relative file paths are equal or not.

```
String path1 = "a/b/c/file.txt";
String path2 = "/A/B/../B/C/file.txt";
```

Actually those two paths point to the same file. But how can I check this?

PS: Doing this for absolute paths works fine, with the approach described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2281769/1817029).

Comment: just convert them to full paths with Path.GetFullPath

Comment: there is a method of the Path class if i'm not wrong to convert to filename in thery absoulte representation...

Comment: The solution is _in_ the question you linked: `System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(pathA).Equals(System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(PathB))`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Path.GetFullPath` ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfullpath%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) to compare the absolute paths of your files.

Comment: This works only if I first remvove the leading slash before. Hence, `"a/b/c/file.txt" != "/A/B/../B/C/file.txt"`