# ToUpperInvariant() – is MSDN wrong on its recommendation?

Tags: .net, string, msdn, toupper

In [Best Practices for Using Strings in the .NET Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465121(v=vs.110).aspx), StringComparison [`OrdinalIgnoreCase`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparison(v=vs.110).aspx) is recommended for case-insensitive file paths. (Let's call it Statement A.)

I can agree with that, because I can create two files in the same directory:

```
é.txt
é.txt
```

Their filenames are not the same, second one is composed from `e` and modifier, so it actually has two letters. (You can try yourself using copy-paste.)

If there was Invariant culture comparison (and not ordinal comparison) in effect, NTFS wouldn't allow these files, because in the same article they explain, that in invariant culture `a + ̊  = å`

But in article on [`String.ToUpperInvariant()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.toupperinvariant(v=vs.110).aspx) there is different recommendation: (Statement B.)

> If you need the lowercase or uppercase version of an operating system identifier, such as a file name, named pipe, or registry key, use the ToLowerInvariant or ToUpperInvariant methods.

I need to create file path collection (in fact `HashSet`) to detect duplicates. So if I will obey statement B when creating the map, I could end with false positives, because abovementioned filenames `é.txt` and `é.txt` will be considered as one. Am I  understanding it correctly that statement B found in MSDN is misleading? Or am I missing something?

I'm about to build a library, preferably without known bugs from start, so I simply don't want to neglect this.

Update:

Statement B seems to have one more issue: ToLowerInvariant() cannot be actually used. Reason (I quote Best practices article): `DO: Use ToUpperInvariant rather than ToLowerInvariant when normalizing strings for comparison.` Actual reason:  `There is a small range of characters that do not roundtrip, and going to lowercase will make these characters unavailable.` ([source](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2005/06/01/424012.aspx#comments))

Comment: I am not entirely sure "the lowercase or uppercase version of an operating system identifier" is meant to be the same as "an unambiguous mapping of an operating system identifier to a lowercase or uppercase version". It could also mean "a mapping of an operating system identifier to a non-unique lowercase or uppercase version that will work the same way regardless of the system's locale".

Comment: OT, but who knows what your library does: NTFS also allows `:`, `*` or `?` in file names. It's just Windows that doesn't support it. It's quite easy to create such files on NTFS under Linux.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper – a good way of reading of that statement... In this context it looks logical. On the other hand, they could either leave out mentioning file names or add a short note on (non-)uniqueness.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Neither uppercasing nor lowercasing is correct when you want to compare strings for equality case-insensitively. In both variants there are characters that mess this up.

The correct way to compare strings case-insensitively is to use one of the insensitive `StringComparison` options (you know that).

The right way to use a data structure case-insensitively is to use one of `StringComparer.*IgnoreCase`. For example:

```
new HashSet<string>(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
```

Do *not* uppercase strings before adding them to a data structure. I would fail that in any code review.

> If you need the lowercase or uppercase version of an operating system identifier

You do not need such as thing. This statement does not apply to your case.

Comment: So in case of NTFS filenames, this means `new HashSet<string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)` (or just `OrdinalCase`, depending on how NTFS case sensitivity is switched in specific case).

Comment: I don't know what kind of comparison NTFS uses. It can be configured. There is a hidden file on each NTFS volume that stores the Unicode case mapping table. I guess it could be arbitrary. Not sure what it is in practice.

Comment: Yes I know that... It means we might actually need something like `NtfsIgnoreCase` comparison, working based on content of that hidden `$UpCase` file :)

Comment: See [this answer of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26231047/3764814) (for short: use `OrdinalIgnoreCase` for file names).

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski – I've actually seen it :) and also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1061224/2392157) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/410502/2392157) noteworthy Q&A. Finally I have used `Dictionary(Of T1, T2)(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)` for my specific need.