# How to ensure all files written are below a given path (prevent directory access)

Tags: c#, directory, parent

We have a C# application which will write files to a configurable location. The set of files (and relative paths) is determined at runtime.

We want to ensure that it cannot write files outside the configured location.

For example, the configured location might be c:\Stuff\Export, it would be an error for the program to write anything under C:\Stuff\Important

Really, I think we can achieve this in two ways:
1) Assert none of the relative paths (files to be written) specify 'Parent directory' (typically "../") - System.Path doesn't specify a "parent directory" path component though (like it has for path separation i.e. System.Path.PathSeparator). I feel a bit cludgey checking for "../" in the string.

2) Assert that all of the final absolute paths that are generated (by combining the output location with the file relative path) *are relative to i.e. underneath the output location*. I'm not exactly sure how to go about this though.

```
Example usage:
Output directory: c:\Stuff\Export
Output path 1: "foo\bar\important.xls"
Output path 2: "foo\boo\something.csv"
Output path 3: "../../io.sys"

Expected final files
1. c:\Stuff\Export\foo\bar\important.xls
2. c:\Stuff\Export\foo\boo\something.csv
3. Should throw exception
```

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C#". We use tags for that purpose on [so].

Comment: can you give an example of your directory to write the file and file input?

Comment: This might help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5617320/given-full-path-check-is-path-is-subdirectory-of-some-other-path-or-otherwise

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you create a [`DirectoryInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.aspx) instance on the two paths, its [`FullName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo.fullname.aspx) property should return the fully qualified, canonical path. So if you just do that for both of the sides you want to compare, you can do this:

```
if (chosenDirectory.FullName != configuredDirectory.FullName)
{
    throw new InvalidOperationException(
        String.Format("Invalid path {0}.", chosenDirectory));
}
```

Since `FullName` is just a string, you can do regular string comparison on the paths, like:

```
if (!chosenDirectory.FullName.StartsWith(configuredDirectory.FullName,
    StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
{
    throw new InvalidOperationException(
        String.Format("Invalid path {0}.", chosenDirectory));
}
```

You can also use the [`Parent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.parent.aspx) property and compare its `FullName` to the chosen directory, if you don't want to allow sub-directories within the configured directory:

```
if (!chosenDirectory.Parent.FullName.Equals(configuredDirectory.FullName,
    StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
{
    throw new InvalidOperationException(
        String.Format("Invalid path {0}.", chosenDirectory));
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Here's a quick solution:

```
string chroot = @"C:\root\child";
string requestedPath = @"..\";
string path = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(chroot, requestedPath));
if (!path.StartsWith(chroot, StringComparison.Ordinal))
    throw new Exception("Oops, caught ya!");
```

edit: 
If you want to know if the given path is a valid directory: `Directory.Exists(path)`

Comment: Note that this compares upper/lowercase. If the actual root path were C:\Root\child then no requestedPath would ever be valid, because C:\Root\child\whatever doesn't start with C:\root\child. On Windows better user OrdinalIgnoreCase.