# How do you filter a list so that no member is a substring of another member

Tags: c#, linq, distinct

I have a list containing string items, but some of the string contains similar text, I am trying to get the distinct list.

My list contains this:

```
-Customers\\Order1
-Customers\\Order1\\Product1
-Customers\\Order2\\Product1
-Customers\\Order2\\Product1\\Price
```

From this list I need to get:

```
-Customers\\Order1\\Product1
-Customers\\Order2\\Product1\\Price
```

Basically I want to omit a string if it is in another string in the list?

Comment: Can you show me some code? Define.. list of strings..  `List<string>` ? Use the `Distinct()` method

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen `Distinct()` alone isn't enough here. Look at the sample output.

Comment: Is the order of the items in the list guaranteed to go from least specific to most specific as in your example input? Or could `-Customers\\Order2\\Product1\\Price` come before `-Customers\\Order2\\Product1`?

Comment: I'm not going to downvote, because I don't want to seem retaliatory. But, I think someone should clean up this wording. Getting a distinct list (as in the first sentence of this question) is NOT the same as getting the output.

Comment: Any cause why you don't use a HashSet?

Comment: @DrewJordan If you read the entire question, it's pretty clear. If you only read the first sentence, of course it's not clear.

Comment: @mason I disagree. Once you read the whole post, you realize that what's asked for in the first sentence isn't actually what's being asked for, so IMHO, the question as a whole is a little unclear and inconsistent. But, obviously, that's my opinion and I just wanted to voice it. I'm OK with whatever the community decides.

Comment: Updated the title to match the problem statement.

Comment: I agree with @DrewJordan, the title is misleading... Seems better now.

Answer (score 6):

You can do that with a bit of LINQ and a `foreach` loop like:

```
List<string> outputList = new List<string>();
foreach (var str in originalList)
{
    if (!outputList.Contains(str)
        && !originalList.Any(r => r!= str && r.Contains(str)))
    {
        outputList.Add(str);
    }
}
```

Considering your `originalList` is defined as:

```
List<string> originalList = new List<string>
{
    "Customers\\Order1",
    "Customers\\Order1\\Product1",
    "Customers\\Order2\\Product1",
    "Customers\\Order2\\Product1\\Price",
};
```

You will get the `outputList` as:

```
Customers\\Order1\\Product1
Customers\\Order2\\Product1\\Price
```

Comment: this looks good. maybe `StartsWith` would be a better option in this case

Comment: @Selman22, Thanks, I thought about it, but this statement "Basically I want to omit a string if it is in another string in the list?", looks like a case for `Contains`, OP can replace `Contains` with `StartsWith` if that is the case.

Comment: Wouldn't the `Any` method makes this solution have O(n^2) performance?  I didn't down vote, just pointing out a concern.

Comment: @SteveMitcham, thanks, but I don't think there is any other way, the comparison has to be done with a substring. *(the downvote since has been removed)*.

Answer (score 5):

If these values are truly paths and you want to handle subdirectories, you need to make sure you are also handling the case where a name is a substring of another name, but they are different paths.  I.E. `Customer\\Order1` and `Customer\\Order10`.

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<string> DistinctBySubString(this IEnumerable<string> strings)
    {
        var results = new List<string>();
        foreach (var s in strings)
        {
            bool add = true;
            for(int i=results.Count-1; i>=0; i--)
            {
                if (IsSubDirectoryOf(results[i],s))
                {
                    results.RemoveAt(i);
                }
                else if (IsSubDirectoryOf(s,results[i]))
                {
                    add = false;
                }

            }
            if (add)
                results.Add(s);
        }
        return results;
    }

    private static bool IsSubDirectoryOf(string dir1, string dir2)
    {
        DirectoryInfo di1 = new DirectoryInfo(dir1);
        DirectoryInfo di2 = new DirectoryInfo(dir2);
        bool isParent = false;
        while (di2.Parent != null)
        {
            if (di2.Parent.FullName == di1.FullName)
            {
                isParent = true;
                break;
            }
            else di2 = di2.Parent;
        }
        return isParent;
    }
}
```

Using it like this:

```
List<string> strings = new List<string>()
{
    "Customers\\Order1",
    "Customers\\Order10",
    "Customers\\Order1\\Product1",
    "Customers\\Order2\\Product1",
    "Customers\\Order2\\Product1\\Price"
};



foreach (var result in strings.DistinctBySubString())
{
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

The directory matching is based on the code from this answer: [Given full path, check if path is subdirectory of some other path, or otherwise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5617320/given-full-path-check-if-path-is-subdirectory-of-some-other-path-or-otherwise)

Answer (score 3):

The problem on the last routine is, you should abort the search in the second list, when there is a match. otherwise it will be still valid on other items.

EDIT: new routine:

```
class Program
{
    private static IEnumerable<string> SelectUnique(IEnumerable<string> list)
    {
        // iterate the list..
        foreach (var item1 in list)
            // you don't want to match the same item.
            if (!list.Where(item2 => item1 != item2)
                // search for items where it start with the current item. (notice the ! before the list.Where)
                .Any(item2 => item2.StartsWith(item1)))
                    yield return item1;
    }


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        List<string> list = new List<string>();
        list.Add("Customers\\Order1\\Product1");
        list.Add("Customers\\Order2\\Product1");
        list.Add("Customers\\Order2\\Product1\\Price");
        list.Add("Customers\\Order1");
        list.Add("Customers\\Order3\\Price");



        var results = SelectUnique(list);

        foreach (var item in results)
            Console.WriteLine(item);

        Console.ReadKey();

    }
}
```

Comment: this will work for the input in the question.But if you have other strings that contains each other, this will return all of them except the shortest one.but the requirement is to get longest string only.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is best done as a LINQ query.

```
var input = new List<string>()
{
    "Customers\\Order1",
    "Customers\\Order1\\Product1",
    "Customers\\Order2\\Product1",
    "Customers\\Order2\\Product1\\Price",
};

var query =
    from x in input
    where !input.Any(y => y != x && y.Contains(x))
    select x;

var result = query.ToList();
```

From which I get:

[image: result]

---

Just in case the actual requirement is to search by subpath and not by substring, then this works:

```
var input = new List<string>()
{
    "Customers\\Order1",
    "Customers\\Order1\\Product10",
    "Customers\\Order1\\Product1",
    "Customers\\Order2\\Product1",
    "Customers\\Order2\\Product1\\Price",
};

var paths = input.ToDictionary(x => x, x => x.Split('\\'));

var query =
    from x in input
    where !input
        .Any(y => y.Length > x.Length
            && paths[x]
                .Zip(paths[y], (p1, p2) => new { p1, p2 })
                .All(p => p.p1 == p.p2))
    select x;

var result = query.ToList();
```

I get this result:

[image: result2]

Comment: @adamdc78 - The OP has only asked about substrings - so it works fine and you get back: "Customers\\Order10", "Customers\\Order1\\Product1", "Customers\\Order2\\Product1\\Price"

Comment: @adamdc78 - Yes, but that is by design. The question specifically asks about substrings. It doesn't ask to work with subpaths.

Comment: @adamdc78 - Correct, I don't believe so either, but if the OP wants to change it we need to wait for him to do it. Otherwise we answer what has been asked.

Comment: @adamdc78 - I've added a subpath solution nevertheless.

Answer (score 2):

If the order of the items doesn't matter, then it's a matter of sorting your list from longest to shortest, and then providing a custom equality comparer to the `Distinct` LINQ method.

The comparer implements both `GetHashCode` and `Equals`.  Since `Equals` won't be called unless the hash codes are equal, you can just take it out by always returning `0`.  The rules for `GetHashCode` state that things that aren't equal can return the same hash code so you aren't breaking semantics here.

The `Equals` method then just compares to see whether the old string starts with the new string.  The new string is passed in as the first argument and the old string is passed in as the second argument.

Our comparator then looks like:

```
public class StartsWithEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<String>
{
   #region IEqualityComparer implementation

   public bool Equals (string x, string y)
   {
      return y.StartsWith (x);
   }

   public int GetHashCode (string obj)
   {
      return 0;
   }

   #endregion
}
```

You can then make the call by using it with the `Distinct` method

```
var foo = list.OrderByDescending(s=> s.Count())
              .Distinct (new StartsWithEqualityComparer ())
              .ToList();
```

Finally, if necessary, you can use the `Sort` method to reorder the list back into the necessary order (e.q alphabetically).