# The Type or Namespace [CanBeNull] could not be found

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have copied a useful class StringExtensions from [Given full path, check if path is subdirectory of some other path, or otherwise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5617320/given-full-path-check-if-path-is-subdirectory-of-some-other-path-or-otherwise) but when I put it in my solution (VS 2013 Pro) I get the error message
     The Type or Namespace [CanBeNull] could not be found and  The Type or Namespace [NotNull] could not be found

from the following code lines

```
 public static string WithEnding([CanBeNull] this string str, string ending)
 public static string Right([NotNull] this string value, int length)
```

My project include using System;
How can I get rid of these errors?

Answer (score 4):

They are part of Resharper Annotations. Install [JetBrains.Annotations](https://www.nuget.org/packages/JetBrains.Annotations/) via Nuget.

Then do `using JetBrains.Annotations;` if the code doesn't have it already.

Alternatively, just remove them from your code.