# Correct way to check if some path refers to something inside specified folder

Tags: c#, directory

For example, I want to find out if specified directory path refers to `Windows` folder or anything inside it:

```
private static bool IsInsideWidowsFolder(string path)
{
    // windowsFolder = "C:\Windows"
    string windowsFolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Windows);

    if (path.Contains(windowsFolder)) returen true
    return false;
}
```

But this will also consider true other strings like:

```
C:\WindowsApp
```

Which class is able to consider that string invalid while considering following as true?

```
C:\Windows\system32
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5617346/440030

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could just add a `\` at the end of your `windowsFolder` path. This will mark the end of the word and allow you to match only the correct pattern: `C:\Windows\`

Looking closer at the problem actually the call :

```
string windowsFolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Windows);
```

returns `C:\WINDOWS` . But the `Contains` method is case sensitive. This would lead to a false match even with this path: `C:\Windows\system32`. You can use [ToLower](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.tolower(v=vs.110).aspx) to make it case insensitive

```
if (path.ToLower().Contains(windowsFolder.ToLower() + "\\"))
```

another approach would be to parse the path up the parent hierarchy using [Directory.GetParent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getparent(v=vs.110).aspx) and check each parent using the [Equals](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c64xh8f9(v=vs.110).aspx) method. It will allow you for a case insensitive comparison if you use the `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase` option

```
private static bool IsInsideWidowsFolder(string path)
{
    // windowsFolder = "C:\WINDOWS"
    string windowsFolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Windows);

    string parent = "";
    while ((parent = Directory.GetParent(path)?.FullName) != null)
    {
        if (windowsFolder.Equals(parent, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            return true;
        }
        path = parent;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: This answer shows pretty much the same: stackoverflow.com/a/5617346/440030 . But your seems better.

Comment: @InfernumDeus ah seems legit. shall we mark it as duplicate ?=!

Comment: @InfernumDeus but actually your question has the case sensitivity part, which lacks in the other question and some of the answers, so I would not vote for a dauplicate

Comment: I consider it connected but not the same. People may search for something like that.

Answer (score 0):

You can ensure both paths have backslashes

```
public static string EnsureBackSlash(this string input)
{
    return Path.GetFullPath(input)
        .TrimEnd(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar, Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar)
        + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Append a backslash on windowsFolder

```
string windowsFolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Windows) + "\\";
```

You may also want to use a case insensitive method for checking such as:

```
return path.IndexOf(windowsFolder, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)==0;
```

Comment: Mong Zhu's answer is more complete, but instead of using Directory.GetParent you should use Path.GetDirectoryName.  Directory will actually use the file system to figure out the parent directory (disk reads involved) while Path will just parse the path string which will be more efficient.