# How to check effectively if one path is a child of another path in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, path

I am trying to determine if one path is a child of another path.

I already tried with:

```
if (Path.GetFullPath(A).StartsWith(Path.GetFullPath(B)) ||
    Path.GetFullPath(B).StartsWith(Path.GetFullPath(A)))
   { /* ... do your magic ... */ }
```

like in [How to check if one path is a child of another path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8091829/how-to-check-if-one-path-is-a-child-of-another-path)  post

But it doesn't work. For example if I write "C:\files" and "C:\files baaa" the code thinks that the "C:\files baaa" is a child of "C:\files", when it isn't, it is only of C:.
The problem is really heavy when I try with long paths, with an amount of childs.

I also tried with "if contains \"... but still not really working in all the chases

What can I do?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean direct child or descendant?

Comment: "C:\files baaa" isn't a valid path, so I'm not sure I understand the issue

Comment: @Harrison Why not? You don't use spaces in your folder names? :S

Comment: @gitsitgo.  Ah, Gotcha. Thanks for pointing out my misunderstanding.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (!Path.GetFullPath(A).TrimEnd(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar).Equals(Path.GetFullPath(B).TrimEnd(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar), StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
    && (Path.GetFullPath(A).StartsWith(Path.GetFullPath(B) + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
    || Path.GetFullPath(B).StartsWith(Path.GetFullPath(A) + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)))
   { /* ... do your magic ... */ }
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried Path.GetFullPath(listBoxItem.ToString()) + "\\") and seems to work.

Comment: Wouldn't that return true if B ~= A?  i.e. "C:\files" and "C:\files\\\" since both point to the same folder, and I believe will eval to true in the above code?

Comment: Yup, if A and B points to the same folder `true` will be returned. It's easy to avoid by checking the equality of their full paths. I'm going to update the sample. Thank you.

Comment: Well, in my code the fist thing I do is to delete the "\\" at the beggining and the end of a path, convert the "/" to "\" and other similar checks. The code is working for me but if u want to improve it, yes, you can :D Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`C:\files` is not a `File`, it's a `Directory`.So you can try this:

```
DirectoryInfo A = new DirectoryInfo(Path.GetFullPath("firstPath"));
DirectoryInfo B = new DirectoryInfo(Path.GetFullPath("secondPath"));

if( B.Parent.FullName == A.FullName || A.Parent.FullName == B.FullName )
```

If you are not looking for a direct parent-child relationship you can try:

```
if (Directory
    .GetDirectories(A.FullName,"*",SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    .Contains(B.FullName) ||

     Directory
    .GetDirectories(B.FullName, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    .Contains(A.FullName))
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to know if folder B was the same as OR was contained within folder A.

The following worked for me:

```
if (A.FullName.Contains(B.FullName))
{
// Path A is equal to or contained within path B. (B is a child of A)
}
```