# Path traversal warning when using Path.Combine

Tags: c#, security, json.net

I am currently using NewtonJSON to load some UI data from a JSON file. However, there is an warning says I have path traversal.

Here is the situation:

[image]

Any idea to remove this security vulnerability?

Comment: Out of interest, what tool are you using that displays this warning?

Comment: @Bids It's one of the feature of Visual Studio.

Comment: @Terence, how do you enable this feature?

Comment: @ÓscarAndreu I think it's a new feature in MS VS Studio 2017.

Answer (score 4):

The path traversal exploit is possible when a path provided by a user or other untrusted source is combined, without checking, with a parent path. The problem is that there are "path traversal" components of paths that enable navigation out of the parent folder.

For example, if you were to combine the following two paths, an absolute path and a relative one:

```
Base/absolute path: C:\WebData
Relative/user path: ..\windows\system32\
```

Then this would yield:

```
C:\windows\system32\
```

As you can imagine, letting someone read or write this directory, which is not the intended `WebData` directory, could be a huge problem, as it could lead to someone learning information about your system or placing exploits that compromise the system, giving control of it to malicious actors.

You can [read more about this exploit](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Path_Traversal).

To deal with this vulnerability properly, you need to ensure that the relative path combined with the parent path is safe. Here are some ways to ensure this:

- The relative path comes from a known trusted source, such as a vetted, internal list.
- The relative path has previously been checked and was stored/maintained in a way that ensures it can be distinguished from untrusted paths, and could not be modified by a user or untrusted agent in the meantime. For example, keeping the path in a string is a *bad* idea. Instead, you would do something like create a `TrustedPath` class that code could only gain an instance of by, in fact, running code that checked that the path is safe.
- The resulting path is checked after combination to ensure it is in the correct location.

You could do the last item like so (all of the below):

1. (As good practice to avoid unnecessary exceptions), use `Path. GetInvalidFileNameChars()`  to check the (untrusted) relative path for invalid characters.
2. Perform `Path.Combine()` as you have done.
3. Ensure the resulting path is still within the original, parent path. This can be done by simply ensuring the resulting path starts with the parent path, but there may be issues with that. So consider [an answer like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23354773/57611) or other code that ensures the resulting path is *truly* a descendant of the desired folder.

Once you have done all this, if the "path traversal" warning is still showing, you can use the menu options in your code quality/security checking tool to annotate this instance of path traversal as safe. You may also want to put a comment with notes explaining why you marked it as safe, which could conceivably include a link to this SO question or one of its answers.

## Note 1

Be careful about reusing a relative path that you have proven combines okay with a specific absolute path. Consider the following:

```
Base/absolute path: C:\WebData\FormElements\SuperForm\windows\
Relative/user path: ..\windows\
```

These two paths would combine safely, however this has not proven that the relative path is always safe to use with *any* absolute path.

## Note 2

Be wary how you go about this. Assuming that relative path traversal always starts with `..\` is a mistake. The following is a valid relative path: `folder\..\..\wheeeWeGotOut`.

## Note 3

Another answer proposes that safety can be guaranteed by simply removing invalid characters, and disallowing paths that contain `..` or `:`. This is problematic for multiple reasons:

- Files in many non-Windows file systems such as HFS or linux can legitimately have these characters. For example, `a:filename` and `another..filename` are perfectly fine (I just tested them). Restricting those characters limits what users can do.
- Trying to improve the filtering to allow legitimate use-cases through is not a good idea. How do you know that you've written this code correctly and didn't miss an edge-case?
- But **most of all**: what if there is an accidental symlink inside of the user's allowed path that points to a file elsewhere in the filesystem? What if the user is able to write a file that can function as a symlink, or has another exploit to cause such a file to be written or copied? The path exploit may not stand alone. It is often a combination of small exploits that leads to large exploits (each next one intersecting with or escalating the previous one). The *only* safe technique to ensure a file or directory is in the proper location is to, after all other filtering and passes and combining have been done, to check that the result is still within the expected location or is a direct descendant (paying attention to symlinks).
- Regarding hard links—that is another matter. Good luck with that one. Don't make hard links. It's very hard to tell that a hard-link even exists, because it's a low-level modification. Read up on it if you're interested.

Comment: Sorry @ErikE, the security you propose can be easily override using this as relative path: c:/windows/win.ini the path.combine function is going to take the second path only.

Comment: Sorry, @ÓscarAndreu, but that is incorrect—the scheme I outlined handles your scenario perfectly fine. Did you miss “the relative path is checked after combination to ensure it is in the correct location.”? If you skip any of my steps, you will indeed incur a risk.

Comment: thanks for your response, think on this scenario:
Base/absolute path: D:\wwwroot\mysite
Relative/user path: C:/windows/
None of your proposed solutions will work properly, the method Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars() will not fail because the relative path is a valid UNC path, and the result of the method Path.Combine will be  C:/windows/

Comment: @ÓscarAndreu And when you check to see if “C:\windows” is outside of the original parent path, you will see that it is and reject it. Look carefully at my third bullet point, “the path is checked after combination to ensure it is in the correct location” and then look at 3. “Ensure the resulting path is still within the original, parent path.” How is my technique going to fail with your proposed input? I am disappointed in your lack of thorough reading and application. It seems as though despite my careful prompting you are still missing a key part of my answer. Will you see it this time?

Comment: I can confidently say that this is the best answer I've found so far. Forcing specific patterns of input paths isn't practical. This, in my opinion, is how it should be done.

Answer (score 0):

A secure way of using Path.Combine can be the next:

```
    public string PathCombine(string path1, string path2)
    {
        if (path2.Contains("..")) return null;
        if (path2.Contains(":")) return null;

        string result = Path.Combine(path1, path2);

        return (result.Equals(path2) ? null : result);
    }
```

Note that this is only an example, not allowed strings check can be  improved.
As additional information you can take a look [here](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/Common/src/CoreLib/System/IO/Path.cs).
If you want to get more information about how this problem can be exploited I recommend you to read the [OWASP documentation](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Path_Traversal).

The fact of check if the result is like the second parameter is due to the behavior of the CombineInternal function that you can check here:

```
    private static string CombineInternal(string first, string second)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(first))
            return second;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(second))
            return first;

        if (IsPathRooted(second.AsSpan()))
            return second;

        return JoinInternal(first.AsSpan(), second.AsSpan());
    }
```

As you can see, if the second variable IsPathRooted, the result is going to be it, and this is a common way to explode this without the need of use '..' characters, think on this example:

Your web is on c:\wwwroot\web1\public\index.html
if you pass as second parameter c:\wwwroot\web1\private\secret.conf you are going to be able to access this file.