# .NET MVC: an endpoint returning a file fails randomly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, http

I created an MVC endpoint returning a file and then deleting it on the server side once the client download is finished. My implementation is based on [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43981710/2545980), with this difference that my endpoint serves plain text files.

```cs
        [Authorize, HttpGet]
        public FileResult DownloadLogFile(string fileName)
        {
            var path = Path.Combine(this.logFilesRoot, fileName);
            var fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None, 4096, FileOptions.DeleteOnClose);
            return File(fs, MediaTypeNames.Text.Plain, fileName);
        }
```

This code works in most of the cases, but for bigger files (more than 40 MB) it randomly fails from time to time:

[image: download failed]

The picture shows my Chrome with an error, but I checked it also with Firefox and Edge, so it's not a problem with browser.

What could be the reason for the random failures?

Some details:

- Net7
- ASPNetCore 6
- Windows OS

#### EDIT

I've changed the endpoint's method to "POST", but still no good. I'm getting `net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET 200` exceptions from JS `fetch` method now.

The code I use on client side is:

```js
    const redirectToLogFile = (fileName: SignalR.IDownloadableLogFileDetails): void => {
        const url = `${Utils.root}home/DownloadLogFile/${fileName.FileName}`;
        fetch(url, { method: "POST" })
        .then(response => response.blob())
        .then(blob => {
            const a = document.createElement("a");
            a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            a.download = fileName;
            a.click();
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
    }
```

Comment: Fun-fact: `Path.Combine` allows arguments to use `..` for [directory-traversal attacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48777564/path-traversal-warning-when-using-path-combine). You should fix that.

Comment: [HTTP `GET` actions should be _safe_](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Safe/HTTP) - but your code as-is violates this (i.e. a `GET` action should never cause anything to be deleted/overwritten server-side, but that's exactly what your code does) - because browsers assume a `GET` action _is_ safe it means they'll gladly make a second `GET` request if they feel like it, which is a likely explanation for what's going on. So change your action to be `POST`-only, and think carefully about what should happen if a request is canceled or aborted.

Comment: Re `..` - not that big problem in my app, as it's for internal use only, but still worth fixing it, so thanks for the hint.
Re: Get method - giving it a go now, thanks.

Comment: @Dai I've switched to POST but still no good. I've updated my question. Hints more than welcome.

Comment: In that case all I can suggest is to improve your code-quality by actually catching and logging exceptions and relevant detail in the request so you can reproduce it with a debugger and browser-simulator (like Postman, or Puppeteer).